# How to install or upgrade to PostgreSQL 8.1 in RHEL 4?

Tags: postgresql, redhat

I'm using RHEL 4 with the default database installed in there (PostgreSQL 7.4), but I want to have PostgreSQL 8.1 installed. What is best, upgrade it or install a new one?

Comment: Neither of which are current by any stretch...

Answer (score 1):

Why? Both versions are EOL and thus not supported anymore. Even 8.2 will be EOL within months, you need version 9.0 or 9.1

Check http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/RPM_Installation for the how-to-install

Comment: i'm just in the progress to replicate the old system at old server to the new one, because the old system was running in RHEL 4 with postgres v.8.1.this system was important.i'm only had RHEL 4 certification so i'm still use this RHEL4 and the maximum version is 8.4.sorry if my english was bad

Answer (score 1):

You need to upgrade to RHEL 5 or 6.  RHEL 5 however will begin the EOL phase out this year and will EOL for regular customers in 2014, with it expiring in 2017 for Extended Life Cycle customers.  In addition RHEL6 is much improved in terms of security with SELinux being integrated for almost all applications in addition to improved performance optimization capabilities.

Comment: i dont have RHEL 5 or 6 license, just the RHEL 4.so i just can upgrade to maximum 8.4 version of postgresql

Answer (score 0):

If you can't upgrade RHEL, you might want to look into switching to CENTOS. If you still can't do that, and must run 8.4 on RHEL4, I would probably compile/install the 8.4 instance from a tarball to a new location, and then use the pg_dump/restore tools to convert the data into the new version of the database.

Comment: i've try to install the 8.4 version but it can't be installed because there is 7.4 version.

Comment: If you do this using a tarball and compiling it yourself, your should be able to install it to a different location, without any conflicts.